# Auth0 accessToken missing when Refresh

Tags: angular, auth0, page-refresh

The login works well, but when i refresh the page it logouts.

[Debugging when Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlLbp.png)

I added in Auth0 Configuration: http://localhost:4200 on **Allowed Web Origins**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.auth.renewTokens();
    }
  }

}
```

It does not show any error message. I´ve put console.log in the functions of renew token or logout and it does not enter.

```
 public renewTokens(): void {
    console.log("adios3");
    this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.localLogin(authResult);
      } else if (err) {
        alert(`Could not get a new token (${err.error}: ${err.error_description}).`);
        this.logout();
      }
    });
  }

  public logout(): void {
    // Remove tokens and expiry time
    console.log("adios1");
    this._accessToken = '';
    this._idToken = '';
    this._expiresAt = 0;

    this.auth0.logout({
      returnTo: window.location.origin
    });
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    console.log("adios4");
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // access token's expiry time
    return this._accessToken && Date.now() < this._expiresAt;
  }
```

**UPDATE: I´ve tried that but still not working**

```
private localLogin(authResult): void {
    // Set the time that the Access Token will expire at
    const expiresAt = (authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + Date.now();
    this._accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
    this._idToken = authResult.idToken;
    this._expiresAt = expiresAt;
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken',this._accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('expiresAt',String(this._expiresAt));
  }
   public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    console.log("adios4");
    this._accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    this._expiresAt = Number(localStorage.getItem('expiresAt'));
    return this._accessToken && Date.now() < this._expiresAt;
  }
```

Comment: where is this code? public logout(). If it's in the AppComponent, then it will be executed. try removing it and putting in a service

Comment: @JackM The logout function is in a service

Comment: are you saving the token in localStorage? if no, save the token and whenever the page loads check if the key exists and update your state accordingly

Comment: @MaxSvid Yes, I´ve tried that. I edit with the code

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Access Token getting stored. Is it in AppComponent or Service?? Save the token in Local Storage as on page refresh your Access Token will be set to ''. On Authentication read the token key from Local storage.

Comment: Yes i´ve tried that and it doesnt work. I edit with the code.

Comment: Remove If block (if(!this._accessToken)) from the code.

Comment: Not working also.  And the behavior of the function is not good either

Comment: Can you please share the function code??. Also pls check the values stored at localstorage.

Comment: I´ve checked the values and are right but isAuthenticated() return false. I´ve shared the code. Thank you

Comment: Ok, now it works when i refresh but it show a infinite loop of alerts with "Could not get a new token (login_required: Login required). auth0". So I delete  this.auth.renewTokens(); in the app Component and it works well but i dont know if its right as it will not refresh the token when it expires.